# Reading from JSON File

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `Movie` class and I have to store a database in the form of JSON File on directory `Database\Movies.JSON`
The movie class has a method for admin to add new movie list to the database.

The thing is, when the first movie is created, the JSON is not an array of `movies` object. When I try to add subsequent movies I need to read from it and create it as an array of movie objects. Is there a neat way to do so on Jackson JSON API?

I am using the latest Jackson 2.6.3

```
public void createMovie() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File f = new File("./Database/Movies.json");
    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { // if existing data exist, read
                                            // from it and append new movie
                                            // data
    } else {
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(f), this);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have since created it as an array of movie objects.

```
objectMapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(f), Collections.singleton(this));
```

But when I try to use the below for handling exisiting datas, it crashes on the first line

```
List<Movie> myMovies = objectMapper.readValue(f,objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Movie.class));
myMovies.add(this);
objectMapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(f), myMovies);
```

Error trace

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2658)
    at entity.Movie.createMovie(Movie.java:167)
```

Sample JSON Data

```
   [
    {
        "movieID": 0,
        "title": "213131 13213 axda",
        "type": "DIGITAL",
        "synopsis": null,
        "director": null,
        "casts": [],
        "status": "COMING_SOON",
        "showTimes": null,
        "cinema": null,
        "mRating": "G",
        "rRating": "_0",
        "reviews": [],
        "totalSales": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid dealing with this array/non array problem, you should always store a json  array in your file. You can add your first movie as an array containing this single element. You can do it with :

```
objectMapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(f), Collections.singleton(this));
```

Comment: Yup, great to create it as an array of `movies`. But can you take a look at why using `List<Movie> movies = objectMapper.readValue(f,objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Movie.class));
    movies.add(this);
    objectMapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(f), movies);` does not work when the file already exists?

Comment: Could you specify the error you have ? I tested it with a dummy movie structure and it works fine providing the json file contains a array.

Comment: It complies fine. Just that when it tries to run line `List<Movie> myMovies = objectMapper.readValue(f,objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Movie.class));` the program crashes. Not sure if some of the attributes are null and some of my own enum type would make any differences

Comment: Do you have the stack trace to help debugging the problem ?

Comment: Not sure if what I updated on the question is what you are asking for

Comment: I guess your problem is now on the data binding of your movie bean. Maybe a problem with some enum values or int/string mapping error.